# How to connect to a docker container from web?

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, containers

I am working on a new project where I need to connect to a docker container from web?
By connect I mean I will create a shell in the website and tat shell will be able to connect to the running container.

I am not able to figure out how to proceed with the project.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You could combine some JavaScript modules. [node-pty](https://github.com/Microsoft/node-pty) and [xterm](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/) being the most important. Additionally, [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) is useful, but could be replaced but something else.

Note: this is not a production ready example. In particular, you should take care of safety measurements, or better yet, let no one but yourself use it.

##### server.js

```js
import { WebSocketServer, createWebSocketStream } from 'ws';
import pty from 'node-pty';

const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 3000 });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    console.log('new connection');

    const duplex = createWebSocketStream(ws, { encoding: 'utf8' });

    const proc = pty.spawn('docker', ['run', "--rm", "-ti", "ubuntu", "bash"], {
        name: 'xterm-color',
    });

    const onData = proc.onData((data) => duplex.write(data));

    const exit = proc.onExit(() => {
        console.log("process exited");
        onData.dispose();
        exit.dispose();
    });

    duplex.on('data', (data) => proc.write(data.toString()));

    ws.on('close', function () {
        console.log('stream closed');
        proc.kill();
        duplex.destroy();
    });

});
```

##### index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/xterm/css/xterm.css" />
    <script src="node_modules/xterm/lib/xterm.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="terminal"></div>
    <script type="module">
        const term = new Terminal();
        term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
        const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
        ws.onmessage = async ({ data }) => term.write(await data.text());
        term.onData((data) => ws.send(data));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: I am using the statics from the node modules folder, in your real code you probably want to use a bundler for this.

I am serving the entire project with nginx on port 8080 for simplicity. And then I start the server with node.

```
docker run -d --rm -p 8080:8080 -v "$PWD:/usr/share/nginx/html" nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged
node server.mjs
```

Afterwards, I can open http://localhost:8080 in my browser, and get a shell.

The dependencies in my package.json are these:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "node-pty": "^0.10.1",
    "ws": "^8.7.0",
    "xterm": "^4.18.0"
  }
```

You can view the code in this repo: https://github.com/bluebrown/web-shell.

Comment: Can you explain the docker command to me?
Why exactly did you run the container with those flags..

Comment: @Binary_Beast, its just one way of many to serve the static files. You can also use other tools, it doesnt matter. As long as you can view your statics in the browser at the end.  This docker command mounts the current directory into the html folder of the nginx image so that nginx will serve the files on port 8080, roughly speaking. You can consult the documentation so see what the individual flags mean. Perhaps docker run --help, is also useful.

Comment: @Binary_Beast, or do you mean the docker command for the ubuntu container?

Comment: Thank you very much, 
my doubt got cleared.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know there is no out of the box solution, you should make your own api executing command on your container running `docker exec <id> <command>` and returning the output, mind escape the command.

However you should know that letting a user run commands inside a docker is dangerous as it could impact your host.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Docker APIs for this (https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/) along with a framework that wraps the APIs. For example refer [dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode).